# Laravel works on two folders in my domain

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have a Laravel project running on a shared hosting. after adding this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Laravel works in site.com/ and site.com/public too.

how to let it work just in the root domain?

Comment: Don't forget [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069319/env-file-is-visible).

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps. You don't need to change in thing in `htaccess` file.

1. Rename `server.php` in your Laravel root folder to index.php
2. Copy the `.htaccess` file from /public directory to your Laravel
   root folder.